# jQueryUI Sortable - cancel-property leaves unable to edit input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jquery-3.2.1.min.js and jquery-ui.min.js in version 1.12.1

I want to make a sortable list and in that list I have certain elements that I want to be not sortable (other sortable lists to be precise). It is important that the input elements remain editable.

```
<ul id="a">
  <li>sometext<input value="1" /></li>
  <li>moretext<input value="2" /></li>
  <li class="b">
    <ul>
      <li>text<input value="3" /></li>
      <li>blarg<input value="4" /></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>last<input value="5" /></li>
</ul>
```

When I initialize the sortable like this:

```
jQuery("#a").sortable();
```

It all works fine as I can edit the input elements and sort at the same time.
But when I add the cancel-property to prevent the sub-lists from being drag-able, then the input fields can't get edited anymore:

```
jQuery("#a").sortable({cancel: ".b"});
```

I do not understand this behavior at all.

I made a codepen of the problem: https://codepen.io/DesmondTMB/pen/oGgjYX

If anyone has a solution for this problem, I would be very grateful. I am trying to get this to behave the way I want since hours.

Thank you!

Comment: Suspect you want `items` with a value like `"> li:not(.b)"`.

Answer (score 1):

the default values of cancel are "input,textarea,button,select,option". When you enter .b only, it overrides the defaults. So you need to add the default to your cancel.

```
jQuery("#a").sortable({cancel: "input, textarea, button, select, option, .b"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your CodePen, I would advise the following:

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("#a").sortable({
    items: "> li:not(.b)" 
  });
  jQuery("#x").sortable();
});
```

Please review: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-items

> Type: **Selector**
>
> Default: `"> *"`
>
> Specifies which items inside the element should be sortable.

This will allow all `li` but not `.b` elements to be sortable, and will leave the Input fields editable.

Comment: That adds some behavior that I do not want, because if the element I can not sort is at the top of the list, I can not drop anything above it anymore. Which is why I used the cancel property instead of excluding items. But in the end it is an improvement, because the edibility of the elements is crucial for me, so it works as a workaround for now. Thank you